# Display .gif image using tkinter, ttk and python3

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to display an image.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
myimage = PhotoImage(file='world.gif')
ttk.Label(root, image=myimage)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this I expect to see my image. But I only see a solid grey image.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the Tkinter object. Something like this (I'm not using ttk here):

```
myimage = PhotoImage(file='world.gif')

label = Label(image=myimage)
label.image = myimage # the reference
label.pack()
```

The garbage collector is trying to discard the Tkinter image object since Tkinter doesn't keep a reference on it. So Tkinter releases the image, Tk widget doesn't, and you get a weird blank image.

Comment: Thanks very much Adam. I had to reference the ttk.Label in a variable: `label = ttk.Label(root,image=myimage)` and then use the pack method
`label.pack()`